# What to do next after the sanity check i.e. overfitting over training subset?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, modeling

I have two years of time-series data taken from two sensors which I have split into 80/10/10 non-overlapping train/val/test splits. The task is to denoise one sensor data into another and I am handling it as a regression problem.

I am following [this website](https://fullstackdeeplearning.com/spring2021/lecture-7/) and considered an already published model (5 convolutional and 1 fully connected layer) which is trained on a similar dataset and same task.

For the sake of sanity check, as per the website, I have trained the model on a subset of trainset (3 months) and tried to overfit it (while evaluating on complete val set), which works fine.

However, I am not sure what to do next from this point on? Shall I just train on the complete trainset now? Or do I increase the layers or play with other hyper params to find more details about my regression problem/data? I would really appreciate your comments. Thank you.

PS. The target value is sparse i.e. more than 85% of the time it is zero.

Comment: What is your overall goal?  Also how did you split your data?  Randomly or training with the early period and validating on the recent?

Comment: The overall goal is to create a successful model in a systematic way instead of random hit and try. I didn't split the data randomly.

Comment: What do you mean by "denoise one sensor data into another"? Or should we rather replace the word "another" with "the other"? I.e. you have two sets of data $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n, \{y_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and you want to consider the regression problem for the data $\{(x_i, y_i)\}_{i=1}^n$? I.e. the two time series have the same length, and the measurements are taken at approximately the same time?

Comment: Also, usually, we use the word time series if we want to imply that data depends on its history. Do you want to imply this? Or would all the pairs $\{(x_i, y_i)\}_{i=1}^n$ be iid?